# How do I replace the bot's message in the loop? DSharp-button

Tags: c#, loops, button, bots

I would like to write some game in a bot in which the text changes very VERY often. But I don't understand how to do it without using declared new var
Please help form a permanent button jump, but without hard code

```
[Command("test_button")]
        public async Task But(CommandContext ctx)
        {
            var button = await ctx.RespondAsync(m => m.WithContent("blya")
            .AddComponents(new DiscordButtonComponent(ButtonStyle.Primary, "button-one", "button")));

            var people = new string[] { "textAAA", "textBBB", "textCCC" };

            var result = await button.WaitForButtonAsync();

            await result.Result.Interaction.CreateResponseAsync(InteractionResponseType.DeferredMessageUpdate).ConfigureAwait(false);
            await button.ModifyAsync(people[0]).ConfigureAwait(false);

            // how to fix it?
            var result2 = await button.WaitForButtonAsync();

            await result2.Result.Interaction.CreateResponseAsync(InteractionResponseType.DeferredMessageUpdate).ConfigureAwait(false);
            await button.ModifyAsync(people[1]).ConfigureAwait(false);

            var result3 = await button.WaitForButtonAsync();

            await result3.Result.Interaction.CreateResponseAsync(InteractionResponseType.DeferredMessageUpdate).ConfigureAwait(false);
            await button.ModifyAsync(people[2]).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I thought it could be done through delegates or => but I'm still new to programming, so I don't understand how to do it
I would be very grateful for advice or hints

Comment: You have to give us more details. I dont't understand what you actually want to achive and I don't think anyone will...

Comment: Is this question about how should loop be declared in C#?

Comment: Sorry, I want to make a button to replace the text. 
Press the button -> change the text -> press the button -> change the text
And do it like that 150 times.
Sorry if there are mistakes in the text, my native language is not English

Comment: Yes, how to declare a loop for it

"var result2 = await button.WaitForButtonAsync();

            await result2.Result.Interaction.CreateResponseAsync(InteractionResponseType.DeferredMessageUpdate).ConfigureAwait(false);
            await button.ModifyAsync(people[1]).ConfigureAwait(false);"

Comment: Well, as I understood you have some button, which should update some text after clicking on it? If so, you should go for something like events. One more thing - are you using some framework? If so, what is it?

Comment: I use the nuget D# I realized I had done something stupid, I just needed to put the code in the for loop

Answer (score 0):

I just needed a loop "for", I'm groggy

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    var result = await one.WaitForButtonAsync();
    await result.Result.Interaction.CreateResponseAsync(InteractionResponseType.DeferredMessageUpdate).ConfigureAwait(false);
    await one.ModifyAsync(text[i]).ConfigureAwait(false); 
}
```